# In iOS7, cannot drag ImageView out of the constraints of parent view to main body?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

In iOS, when dragging an `UIImageView` (red square) using `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in a `scrollview` (bar at bottom within another `UIImageView`), I cannot drag out of the constraints of the bar into the main body `UIView` sitting above? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

For clarity, here’s my view structure:

```
view (main controller)
  |  
  ——> view (nav bar)
  |
  ——> view (main body)
  |
  ——> view (yellow bar)
              |——> scroll view (dynamic)
                     |
                     ——>view (dynamic - wider than scroll view)
                          |
                          ——> image view (dynamically created red square)
```

which looks like:

[image]

what I'm doing:

Basically, in `ViewController`.m, I’m programmatically creating a `scrollview` (`barScrollView`) and adding it to a view (yellow bar). I dynamically create another new view and pass it to a function and within that function, in a loop, I dynamically create several `ImageView` items (red squares), enable `userInteractionEnabled` on them, create the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and add it to each `ImageView` created, then add them to the view that was passed in. Lastly, I add the view that was passed in to the `scrollview`

my code:

In storyboard:

```
- dragged in 3 UIViews (see image above)
```

In ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *navBar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *mainBodyView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *yellowBar;

@end
```

In ViewController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60);
    CGRect containerRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 820, 60);
    UIScrollView *barSV = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:barRect];     
    [_yellowBar addSubview:barSV];
    UIView *redSquaresContainerView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:containerRect];
    [self generateRedSquares:redSquaresContainerView]; 
    [barSV addSubview:redSquaresContainerView];
    barSV.contentSize =containerRect.size;
}


-(void)generateRedSquares:(UIView*) containerView{
    int x =0;
    for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        CGRect redSquareRect = CGRectMake(x, 10, 30, 30);
        UIImageView* aRedSquareView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:redSquareRect];
        aRedSquareView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];    
        aRedSquareView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; 
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *dragRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer      
          alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dragRedSquare:)];
        [aRedSquareView addGestureRecognizer:dragRecognizer];
        [containerView addSubview:aRedSquareView];
        x+=60;
    }
}


- (void) dragRedSquare:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{
    static CGRect originalFrame;
    if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        originalFrame = recognizer.view.frame;
    } else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // Drag moved
        CGPoint translate = [recognizer translationInView:recognizer.view];
        CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(originalFrame.origin.x + translate.x,
                                 originalFrame.origin.y + translate.y,
                                 originalFrame.size.width,
                                 originalFrame.size.height);    
        if (CGRectContainsRect(recognizer.view.superview.bounds, newFrame)){
            recognizer.view.frame = newFrame;
        }
    } else if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
        // Drag completed
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards, make sure that that UIElement is UNDERNEATH the view you want it to go over.

So, For example in the image below, I want the UIImage to be drawn over all other view so I can drag it over everything else on the screen.

[image: Example of Where your MOVABLE image should be in the storyboard]

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the advice. Not sure if I got what you meant, but I do have my view (red square bar) where I'll place my scrollview and red square in already at the bottom

Comment: In the storyboard do you have CLIPS SUBVIEW selected?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to drag the ImageView out of the constraints of the then try to bring it to the font of the main view instead of adding it as a child you may need to addict as a sibling to pan across the view

Comment: Thanks, Geet. Are you suggesting I bring the ImageView (red sq) to the front? It needs to sit in the view I'm going to add to the scrollview, so I can dynamically populate it (and scroll if there's too many).

Comment: yes try bringing it to the front, and don't add it within any container view, addd it as a sibling to the view you want to drag it to

Comment: Hi Geet. Thanks. I need to add the (red sq) ImageView to the container view in order to have scroll to work. I tried including [self.view bringSubviewToFront:aRedSquareView]; within my for loop in generateRedSquares to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and hopefully will help someone else down the line. Regardless, if you're working with scrollviews/gestures and stuck, watching the below video is truly helpful. (I'll try to elaborate more later..thanks)

In dragRedSquare function, include the following two lines w/in the if statement:

```
- (void) dragRedSquare:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer{

...

if ([recognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    recognizer.view.center = [self.view convertPoint:recognizer.view.center fromView:recognizer.view.superview];
    [self.view addSubview:recognizer.view];
}

...

}
```

Resource: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/
(Advanced Scrollviews and Touch Handling Techniques: ~28min mark)